# PHP google web login not showing profile info

Tags: php, google-signin

I want to implement the google login via PHP in my website and I'm following the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/).

Everything seems to work fine in the sense that I finally get logged in, but not in the desired way: in fact, I press on the "SignIn" button, then a popup appears asking for username/password/permissions, then I click OK and then nothing else happens. Then, I open an other browser tab to the google homepage and I see that I'm actually logged in!

I'd have expected that the page signin.php in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) was redirecting me to index.html to show a message about my profile info but that's not the case. If I access to index.html actually nothing happens, I just see the red button. Any clue why the redirect doesn't work?

Comment: Quote: "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

Please, check redirect url in google application setting.
might be that redirect url wrong.

Comment: I'm redirecting to http://mywebsite.com/gplus-quickstart-php-master and the javascript origin is set to http://mywebsite.com
Furthermore, when accessing to signin.php, the JS console says: "http://mywebsite.com/signin.php/activities 404 (Not Found)". I don't understand what is going on.